# How is the skipping implemented in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch, skip, fallback, chunks

I was wondering how I could determine in my `ItemWriter`, whether Spring Batch was currently in chunk-processing-mode or in the fallback single-item-processing-mode. In the first place I didn't find the information how this fallback mechanism is implemented anyway.

Even if I haven't found the solution to my actual problem yet, I'd like to share my knowledge about the fallback mechanism with you.

Feel free to add answers with additional information if I missed anything ;-)

Comment: can you explain the real world problem which brings you to the question "how do the writer know the current processing-mode"?

Comment: Sure :-) I'm storing a business log (beside my technical logging). In this log, messages for each item should only appear once. In case of an exception during processing I will also write error logs for this item in the business log.

If an item has been processed but rolled back, I'm not interested in its error logs. I only want to log these error if I'm in single item processing. Otherwise if I'm in chunk mode, I might log errors for items which are fine, just because they are in a bad chunk.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The implementation of the skip mechanism can be found in the [FaultTolerantChunkProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.html) and in the [RetryTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/retry/support/RetryTemplate.html).

*Let's assume you configured [skippable exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringSkip) but no [retryable exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#retryLogic). And there is a failing item in your current chunk causing an exception.*

Now, first of all the whole chunk shall be written. In the processor's `write()` method you can see, that a `RetryTemplate` is called. It also gets two references to a `RetryCallback` and a `RecoveryCallback`.

Switch over to the `RetryTemplate`. Find the following method:

```
protected <T> T doExecute(RetryCallback<T> retryCallback, RecoveryCallback<T> recoveryCallback, RetryState state)
```

There you can see that the `RetryTemplate` is retried as long as it's not exhausted (i.e. exactly once in our configuration). Such a retry will be caused by a *retryable exception*. Non-retryable exceptions will immediately abort the retry mechanism here.

After the retries are exhausted or aborted, the `RecoveryCallback` will be called:

```
e = handleRetryExhausted(recoveryCallback, context, state);
```

**That's where the single-item-processing mode will kick-in now!**

The RecoveryCallback (which was defined in the processor's `write()` method!) will put a lock on the input chunk (`inputs.setBusy(true)`) and run its `scan()` method. There you can see, that a single item is taken from the chunk:

`List<O> items = Collections.singletonList(outputIterator.next());`

If this single item can be processed by the `ItemWriter` correctly, than the chunk will be finished and the `ChunkOrientedTasklet` will run another chunk (for the next single items). This will cause a regular call to the `RetryCallback`, but since the chunk has been locked by the `RecoveryTemplate`, the `scan()` method will be called immediately:

```
if (!inputs.isBusy()) {
    // ...
}
else {
    scan(contribution, inputs, outputs, chunkMonitor);
}
```

So another single item will be processed and this is repeated, until the original chunk has been processed item-by-item:

```
if (outputs.isEmpty()) {
    inputs.setBusy(false);
```

That's it. I hope you found this helpful. And I even more hope that you could find this easily via a search engine and didn't waste too much time, finding this out by yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach to my original problem (the ItemWriter would like to know, whether it's in chunk or single-item mode) could be one of the following alternatives:

---

- Only when the passed chunk is of size one, any further checks have to be done
- When the passed chunk is a `java.util.Collections.SingletonList`, we would be quite sure, since the `FaultTolerantChunkProcessor` does the following:

  **List items = Collections.singletonList(outputIterator.next());**

  Unfortunately, this class is private and so we can't check it with `instanceOf`.
- In reverse, if the chunk is an `ArrayList` we could also be quite sure, since the Spring Batch's `Chunk` class uses it:

  **private List items = new ArrayList();**
- One blurring left would be buffered items read from the execution context. But I'd expect those to be ArrayLists also.

Anyway, I still find this method too vague. I'd rather like to have this information provided by the framework.

---

An alternative would be to hook my `ItemWriter` in the framework execution. Maybe `ItemWriteListener.onWriteError()` is appropriate.

Update: The `onWriteError()` method will not be called if you're in single-item mode and throw an exception in the `ItemWriter`. I think that's a bug a filed it: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-2027

So this alternative drops out.

---

Here's a snippet to do the same without any framework means directly in the writer

```
    private int writeErrorCount = 0;

@Override
public void write(final List<? extends Long> items) throws Exception {
    try {
        writeWhatever(items);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        if (this.writeErrorCount == 0) {
            this.writeErrorCount = items.size();
        } else {
            this.writeErrorCount--;
        }

        throw e;
    }
    this.writeErrorCount--;
}

public boolean isWriterInSingleItemMode() {
    return writeErrorCount != 0;
}
```

Attention: One should rather check for the *skippable exceptions* here and not for `Exception` in general.

Comment: We can't call instanceof on the singleton list, but this works:  `Class<?> singletonListClazz = Class.forName( "java.util.Collections$SingletonList" );
  
  boolean retrying = false;
  if( items.getClass().equals( singletonListClazz ) ){
   retrying = true;
  }`

Comment: @slh777 Thanks for your advice. That would work indeed. However, I'm not happy with this approach since we heavily rely on the implementation details of the framework (i.e. a SingletonList is returned, when in SingleItemMode). I'd rather like to see this encapsulated by the framework. :-(