# Spring batch onProcessError Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW not working

Tags: spring-batch, spring-transactions

I'm using spring batch 3.0.7 with java config.

While trying to log process errors to my database in a `@onProcessError` method my insertions are being rolled back. After searching around I found out I should've annotated my method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` which I did, but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Also, I tried creating an applicationContext.xml file and declaring `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to enable transaction annotations. Nothing changed.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/22546021/7269827
Still would like to understand the deal with transaction propagation not working..