# What is the idle way of handling Spring batch's writer's failure while writing on Oracle DB?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Using Spring Batch's JDBCTemplate, I am trying to write data on Oracle DB. Is there any failover mechanism which can help me to process other requests if one query fails to execute ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch skip exception for ItemWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522681/spring-batch-skip-exception-for-itemwriter)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine: it didn't but found solution with SkipPolicy.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception in your batch writer and log as bad records instead of throwing the exception. This will allow next chunk/batch to execute.

Comment: Well... I had earlier done that but it didn't seem elegant as a generic approach to undertake.